# how to work with glusterfs-hadoop plugin?

Tags: hadoop-plugins

i installed glusterfs and works fine, after that i installed hadoop 1.x and works fine with hdfs, but when i use glusterfs-hadoop plugin to use glusterfs as the filesystem backend for my hadoop i get error, i use github site for glusterfs-hadoop plugin. and copy jar file to hadoop library directory, and change my core-site.xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>

<property>
<name>fs.glusterfs.impl</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.glusterfs.GlusterFileSystem</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>glusterfs://fedora1:9010</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.glusterfs.impl</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.local.GlusterFs</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>fs.glusterfs.volumes</name>
<value>test1</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>fs.glusterfs.volume.fuse.test1</name>
<value>/mnt/Hadoop</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

and when execute start-mapred.sh, jobtracker and tasktracker start whitout any problem, but when execute this command "hadoop fs -mkdir ossl" i get this output:

```
15/04/14 12:52:53 INFO glusterfs.GlusterVolume: Initializing gluster volume..
15/04/14 12:52:53 INFO glusterfs.GlusterFileSystem: Configuring GlusterFS
15/04/14 12:52:53 INFO glusterfs.GlusterFileSystem: Initializing GlusterFS,  CRC disabled.
15/04/14 12:52:53 INFO glusterfs.GlusterFileSystem: GIT INFO={git.commit.id.abbrev=f0fee73, git.commit.user.email=bchilds@redhat.com, git.commit.message.full=Merge pull request #122 from childsb/getfattrparse

Refactor and cleanup the BlockLocation parsing code, git.commit.id=f0fee73c336ac19461d5b5bb91a77e05cff73361, git.commit.message.short=Merge pull request #122 from childsb/getfattrparse, git.commit.user.name=bradley childs, git.build.user.name=Unknown, git.commit.id.describe=GA-12-gf0fee73, git.build.user.email=Unknown, git.branch=master, git.commit.time=31.03.2015 @ 00:36:46 IRDT, git.build.time=12.04.2015 @ 14:45:49 IRDT}
15/04/14 12:52:53 INFO glusterfs.GlusterFileSystem: GIT_TAG=GA
15/04/14 12:52:53 INFO glusterfs.GlusterFileSystem: Configuring GlusterFS
15/04/14 12:52:53 INFO glusterfs.GlusterVolume: Initializing gluster volume..
15/04/14 14:36:01 INFO glusterfs.GlusterVolume: Gluster volume: test at : /mnt/hadoop
15/04/14 14:36:01 INFO glusterfs.GlusterVolume: Working directory is : /
15/04/14 14:36:01 INFO glusterfs.GlusterVolume: Write buffer size : 131072
15/04/14 14:36:01 INFO glusterfs.GlusterVolume: Default block size : 67108864
15/04/14 14:36:01 INFO glusterfs.GlusterVolume: Directory list order : fs ordering
15/04/14 14:36:01 INFO glusterfs.GlusterVolume: File timestamp lease significant digits removed : 0
mkdir: Error undefined volume:fedora1:9010 in path: glusterfs://fedora1:9010/ossl
```

please help me, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken this should work:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>glusterfs:///fedora1:9010</value>
</property>
```